# I want to Scrape the article from this site including feature Video url or Image url with all paraghraphs, headings in oder using scrapy in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I want to Scrape the article from this site including the feature Video URL or Image URL with all paragraphs, and headings in order except the text not related to the article but wrapped in the main article div class, by using scrapy in python. In short, I am failed to get the URL of the feature video URL or feature image from this article and got problems while text from this article.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "travelandleisure"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = input("Enter the article url: ")
        
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        try:
            Author = ', '.join(set([x.strip() for x in response.xpath('//a[@class="mntl-attribution__item-name"]/text()').extract()]))
        except IndexError:
            Author = "NULL"
        
        url = response.url
        
        try:
            Category = response.xpath('//*[@id="mntl-text-link_1-0"]/span/text()').get()
        except IndexError:
            Category = "NULL"

        Headlines = response.xpath('//*[@id="article-heading_1-0"]/text()').get().replace("\n","")

        
        
        Source = response.xpath('//*[@id="mntl-text-block_1-0"]/text()').get().replace("\n", "")
        
        Published_Date = response.css('div.mntl-attribution__item-date::text').get().split("on ")[1].replace(",","")#Updated on June 8, 2022
        Published_Date = datetime.strptime(Published_Date, "%B %d %Y").date()
        
        #================Waiting for Stack answer====================
        
        Feature_Image = "NULL" #Please tell the code for feature Image or Video
        
        Content =  "NULL" #Please tell the code for Scrape the all text, paragraph and heading but in sorting as in the article but not include the text that not belong to article but wrapped in this article div " <div class="loc article-content"> "

        yield{
            'Category':Category,
            'Headlines':Headlines,
            'Author': Author,
            'Source': Source,
            'Publication Date': Published_Date,
            'Feature_Image': Feature_Image,
            'Skift Take': skift_take,
            'Article Content': Content
        }
            # =============== Data Store +++++++++++++++++++++
        Data = [[Category,Headlines,Author,Source,Published_Date,Feature_Image,Content,url]]

        cols = ['Category','Headlines','Author','Source','Published_Date','Feature_Image','Content','URL']
        try:
            opened_df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Public/pagedata.csv')
            opened_df = pd.concat([opened_df,pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = cols)])
        except:
            opened_df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = cols)

        opened_df.to_csv('C:/Users/Public/pagedata.csv', index= False) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings = get_project_settings()
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(NewsSpider)
    
    process.start()
```

Here is the website URL `https://www.travelandleisure.com/travel-news/where-can-americans-travel-right-now-a-country-by-country-guide`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is given a way of the possible solutions.

Only for the video link/video image url entirely depends on JavaScript and scrapy can't render JS that's why it's not possible to grab  video image url using scrapy only.

```
import scrapy
import datetime
import pandas as pd
class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "articles"
    def start_requests(self):
        #https://www.travelandleisure.com/travel-news/where-can-americans-travel-right-now-a-country-by-country-guide
        
        url = input("Enter the article url: ")
        
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):

        data = []

        Author = ', '.join(set([x.strip() for x in response.xpath('//a[@class="mntl-attribution__item-name"]/text()').extract()]))
        Category = response.xpath('//*[@id="mntl-text-link_1-0"]/span/text()').get()
        Headlines = response.xpath('//*[@id="article-heading_1-0"]/text()').get().replace("\n","")
        Source = response.xpath('//*[@id="mntl-text-block_1-0"]/text()').get().replace("\n", "")
        Published_Date = response.css('div.mntl-attribution__item-date::text').get().split("on ")[1].replace(",","")#Updated on June 8, 2022
        Published_Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(Published_Date, "%B %d %Y").date()
        #print(Author,Category,Source,Headlines, Published_Date)
        #Feature_Image = "NULL" [only for video]because video link/entirely depends on JavaScript and scrapy can't render JS that's why it's not possible to grab  video image url using scrapy only
        Feature_Images = ''.join([x.get() for x in response.xpath('//*[@class="img--noscript universal-image__image"]/@src')][:-1])
        #print(Feature_Images)
        Content = ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="mntl-sc-page_1-0"]//text()').getall()).strip()
        #print(Content)

        d = {
            'Category':Category,
            'Headlines':Headlines,
            'Author': Author,
            'Source': Source,
            'Publication Date': Published_Date,
            'Feature_Image': Feature_Images,
            'Article Content': Content
            }
        #yield d
        data.append(d)
        

        df = pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('out.csv',index=False)

        #print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks this is working but it's not breaking lines after finishing any paragraph or heading, It's very hard to read the text after scraping.

Comment: remove: .replace('\n\n','')

Comment: I did the same before you suggest but instead, it's breaking the line. It writes the same \n\n at the end of the paragraph or heading.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how can I get this XPath  " '//*[@id="mntl-sc-page_1-0"]//text()' "for the whole content of the site for any future article?

Comment: Actuallly, the above xpath expression willl select  or not  any future whole  article that completely depends on the HTML DOM structure. Just test  and verify your future articles  xpath expression with the help of  chrome devTools then if  it selects if not then modify a bit your xpath expression. Thanks